# Android: Expandable list view move group title to left of child

Tags: android, expandablelistview

Is it possible to move the group title to the left of the child using expandable list view?

**Parent group1**     Child 1.1 
                          
              Child 1.2

**Parent group2**
     Child 2.1 
                              
           Child 2.2

My XML files:

**Expandable_list_view_page.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**parent.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvParentTitle1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:text="parent 1"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvParentTitle2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:text="parent 2"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvParentTitle3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:text="parent 3"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Child.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingTop="5dp"
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvChildText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="child"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post xml files for the layout which you have created

Comment: You can't move a child into a group (and it wouldn't make sense).

Comment: Actually the children stay in the same location. Normally, in a expandable listview the group title is above the children. I wanted to know if there is a possibility to move the group title to the left of the children.

Comment: How would the groups expand then?

Comment: In the example given above, the parent groups are already expanded. When expanded, Parent group 1 will show Child 1.1 and Child 1.2 and when collapsed it would display its parent only i.e Parent group 1. The only difference between the default expandable list view and what I want to achieve is that, in the default view, the parent groups are displayed on the top of their respective children, my view needs the parents on the left of their children rather than on the top.